# How to remove string following a specific word

Tags: windows, sed

I am trying to remove string starting with a specific word in my manifest file. The file containing lines looks like:

```
<assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT" version="9.0.21022.8" processorArchitecture="x86" **publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b**"></assemblyIdentity>
```

I want to remove publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b" from it.

I did: `sed -e "s/publicKeyToken=\"[0-9]*[a-z]*\*//g"`, but nothing gets changed. I can't use publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b" to do replace, because the contents between the "" may change.

Anyone knows the right way to do it?

Comment: Are there actually those asterisks among the publicKeyToken attribute, or did you add those to try to emphasize it?

Comment: Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: The asterisks among publickeytoken attribute are to emphasize it. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When using the Sed command you need `-i` to change the file. Without you the -i it will print to stdout and you can check to see if the command will work for you.

try `sed -i "s/publicKeyToken=\"[0-9][a-z]*//g"`

Also, there is a command to delete a line that start with something. if you want to delete the line publicKeyToken you can use

`sed -i '/pattern to match/d' ./infile`
ie `sed -i '/publicKey/d' yourfile.text`
This site has some good help on what the commands do, 
[Sed help](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-62h)

See also [Stack overflow answer to delete line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-a-line-containing-a-specific-string-using-sed)

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly discourage you to use regex for manipulating XML. There are other tools out there that can help you better than `sed` can, at least for this instance. One such tool is the excellent [XMLStarlet toolkit](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/download.php). It's available under Windows, Linux and MacOS.

That said, if you still would like to continue using `sed`, then one thing that I immediately see that causing the problem is this bit here: `[0-9]*[a-z]*`. It only matches text that begin with zero or more numbers followed by zero or more letters. What you'd need is `[0-9a-f]{16}`.

Have a look at these Regex sandboxes. They're great to test your regex:

http://www.regexr.com/

http://www.rubular.com/

http://regexpal.com/

---